# how do I include native library in rubymotion

Tags: objective-c, ruby, rubymotion

I want to include some native project in my rubymotion project. Anyone faces this problem before because the vendor do not provide cocoapod yet.

Thanks

Comment: http://paulsturgess.co.uk/blog/2013/05/15/using-native-objective-c-cocoapod-libraries-in-rubymotion/

Comment: ya actually i checked this out before...but hows the structure? the native library not providing is not cocoapod. I think use in cocoapod will throw errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll just need to copy the required files in to the vendor folder and require them in your Rakefile.

For example. With these two libraries https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh and https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage the following in your Rakefile will work.

```
app.vendor_project("vendor/SDWebImage.framework", :static, products: ["SDWebImage"], headers_dir: "Headers")

app.vendor_project("vendor/SVPullToRefresh", :static, cflags: "-fobjc-arc")
```

The first library was .framework bundle whereas the second was just .h and .m files in a folder.

You can find some more information on requiring 3rd party libraries here:

http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/project-management/#_vendoring_3rd_party_libraries

Comment: Hmm, @willrax can you explain how the code statement point to which folder? in SDWebImage github, there is no SDWebImage.framework folder, what is headers_dir 'actually point to ?  I checked my project, it dont have .a file, does it matter?

Comment: I tried and it have no error, but it do give some errors which seems like will cause me trouble next time..warning: (i386) /Users/focus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MOLPayLibrary.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MOLPayLibrary.build/Objects-normal/i386/SuccessAuth.o unable to open object file
warning: (i386) /Users/focus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MOLPayLibrary.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MOLPayLibrary.build/Objects-normal/i386/Webdelgate.o unable to open object file

How do I properly import without errors?

Comment: The framework file for SDWebImage comes when you download the release zip from GitHub. If your library doesn't have this you'll need to use the second option and manually copy the .m and .h files into a vendor folder.